# Shiny Dashboard DT::renderDataTable.. output not rendered.. was stuck at processing... fixed it by making it "FALSE" in options. yet no output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have two tabpanel in shiny dashbaord where in one (Tab - "Data Summary") the reactive output DT::dataTableOutput the table is rendered. On the other one (Tab -"Raw Data"), I was only seeing  ***Processing....*** but no table being rendered. So added Processing = FALSE in options, which removed the processing.. banner.. yet I see no output rendered.

**Input data frame: (dat) **

```
        Ad.ID   Coder

        75905818    deroy
        75910661    deroy
        75914385    deroy
        75902382    deroy
        75902383    jishuroy
        75902384    jishuroy
        75902386    jishuroy
        75902391    jishuroy
        75902393    jishuroy
        75902396    jishuroy
        75902418    jishuroy
        75902419    jishuroy
        75902421    jishuroy
        75902422    mrroy
        75902423    mrroy
        75902424    mrroy
        75902432    mrroy
        75902435    mrroy
        75902442    mrroy
        75902443    rande
        75902446    rande
        75902452    rande
        75902454    rande
        75914354    rande
        75914361    rande
        75915439    rande
        75915440    rande
        75915449    rande
        75915453    rande
        75915471    rande
        75915472    rande
        75915522    rande
        75905841    jishuroy
        75905842    mrroy
        75905867    mrroy
        75905869    mrroy
        75905870    deroy
        75905871    deroy
        75905887    deroy
        75905888    deroy
        75905889    deroy
        75905890    deroy
```

Below is the code I have now.

```
set.seed(4656)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

# Load data file & Model --------------------------------------------------

setwd("xxx....")

files <- list.files(pattern = '*.csv')    

y=NULL

for(i in files ) {
  x <- read.csv(i, header=TRUE, skip= 8,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  y= rbind(y,x)
}

dat <- y[,c(9,19)]

dat <- dat[!apply(is.na(dat) | dat == "", 1, all),]



# Simple header -----------------------------------------------------------

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Test)", titleWidth = 500)

# No sidebar --------------------------------------------------------------

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 300,

  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Inputs to Generate Audit Sample", icon = icon("list-ol"),
             # Input directly under menuItem

             pickerInput("in5","Coder", c(unique(as.character(dat$Coder))),options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T),
             numericInput("num", "Audit Sample (%)", value = 25) 
    )
  ),

  sidebarMenu( 
    menuItem("Export Audit Samples", icon=icon('download')),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download ...")    

  )  
)

# Compose dashboard body --------------------------------------------------

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      title = "Testing",
      # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
      id = "tabset1", height = "800px", width = "50px",
      tabPanel("Data Summary", DT::dataTableOutput("summary")),
      tabPanel("Raw Data", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))  
    )

  )
)

# Setup Shiny app UI components -------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin="blue")

# Setup Shiny app back-end components -------------------------------------


server = function(input, output,session) {


  data <- reactive({

    validate(
      need(input$in5 != "Please Select Coder", "Please select Coder to view number of available records & sample count"))


    dist <- as((count(dat, "Coder")),"data.frame")

    dist$sample <- ceiling((dist[,2]*(input$num/100)))

    dist

    dist[dist$Coder %in% input$in5, ]

  })

  # Generate summary
  output$summary <- DT::renderDataTable({

    d <- data()

    DT::datatable(d, rownames = FALSE, escape = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                  caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
                    style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center;',
                    'Team Selection: ', htmltools::em('Select your team by using picklist in agent column')),
                  #caption = 'Select your team by using picklist in agent column', 
                  colnames = c('Agent Name' = 'Coder', 'Number of Ads' = 'freq',"Sample Size"= 'sample'),
                  filter = 'top', options = list(pageLength = 15, autoWidth = TRUE)) 

  })



  data1 <- reactive({

    validate(
      need(input$in5 != "Please Select Coder", "Please select Coder to view number of available records & sample count"))


    names(dat)[2]<-"ID"

    observe({
      print("Renaming done")
    })


    per <-(input$num/100)

    observe({
      print("sample size captured")
    })

    new_df <- dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_frac(per,replace = FALSE)

    observe({
      print("Samples generated")
    })

    new_df$ID <- gsub(" ", "", new_df$ID)

    observe({
      print("WhiteSpaces Removed")
    })

    inFile <- c(input$in5)

    observe({
      print("Input Filter Captured")
    })

    exp <- new_df[new_df$ID %in% inFile, ]

    observe({
      print("Ouptut Filtered")
    })

    exp

  })

  # Generate table of Samples
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    d1 <- data1()

 DT::datatable(d1, extensions = 'Responsive', rownames = FALSE, escape = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
          caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
            style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center;',
            'Team Selection: ', htmltools::em('Select your team by using picklist in agent column')),
          #caption = 'Select your team by using picklist in agent column', 
          # colnames = c('Agent Name' = 'Coder', 'Number of Ads' = 'freq',"Sample Size"= 'sample'),
          filter = 'top', options = list(pageLength = 15, autoWidth = TRUE,processing=FALSE)) 

  })



  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(c(input$in5), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(exp, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
# Render Shiny app --------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Have been breaking my head over this for the last 30 hours.. Any help will be a BIG help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the escape parameter. You only have two columns but three values and datatable throws an error message. You notices it when you run it in console but not in the (web)browser. Just remove one of the values and it runs perfectly

Comment: Thanks @Bertil Baron, I removed escape parameter.  The table is not generated. 
"No data available in table" . Is there a problem in how I'm trying to filter by ID in my reactive session?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bertil, your suggestion pointed me out to the issue. The problem was in the way I was trying to filter out and capture picker input.

Changed existing code to:

```
per <-(input$num/100)

newdf <- dat %>% group_by(Coder) %>% sample_frac(per,replace = FALSE)

newdf

newdf[newdf$Coder %in% input$in5, ]
```

Solved it!